# How to file stipend on ESTA Tourist VWP

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs

I was invited for a conference/meeting to the US for graduate students organized by an US cooperation.
Our costs were supposed to be reimbursed by the cooperation in a form of a stipend.
After the event, I was sent an 8BEN IRS form, which I am supposed to send the company to receive my reimbursement.
I was not aware that I would need to file any tax report to the IRS and mistakenly travelled using the ESTA tourist VWP.

Is it possible to file this stipend legally on the ESTAT VWP? If so how do I declare the reimbursement correctly?

Comment: Why do you consider it a mistake that you travelled on VWP/ESTA? If eligible that is exactly how you should have traveled. I see no connection between W-8BEN and your reimbursement. Reimbursement of expenses is usually not considered income and there would be no need of W-8BEN. In any case W-8BEN is not a tax report. Traveling on VWP or visa would make no difference to whether you should fill it in or not.